# Do you need a special type of screw to mount a NEMA 3R box?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

I need to mount a NEMA 3R Meter base and panel on a temp pole. There are screw knockouts on the back of the panels, but is there something that needs to be done to stop water from coming in the screw holes once they are opened?

I was considering using decking screws since they are water resistant and have decent shear strength. Is that OK? Do I need rubber washer or caulk or something on the screws/holes to keep the water out?

This will be inspected. NEC 2014.

Comment: A rubber washer would be helpful. These should come with the panel and meter base.

Comment: @RetiredMasterElectrician: nothing comes with meter bases and panels anymore. The boxes have a big hole in the top and they make you buy the top hub or top closer plate separate. No screws or anything else come with.

Comment: I wasn't answering your question. Iwas simply making a comment. In answer to your question, if you look at the panel or base you will notice that all pre punched holes are below the bus and electrical equipment we call the guts. So the obvious would tell you that this area can get moisture in there. So if you have mounting holes in the lower area you do not need to waterproof them and if they are above it you do. As far as your screws I would not use anything less than a #10 size or an 1/8" if you bolt it. And I still like Harper's comments.

Comment: Also if you have to have a conduit opening above the lower area, then you must install a weatherproof hub like the one you mentioned or a Myers Hub. The main idea is to prevent water from dripping on a live bus or equipment. Water and electric bad.

Answer (score 2):

Generally the reliable way to mount a panel like this on a pole is to mount a piece of exterior plywood to the pole - then mount the meter base to the plywood.

One who is exceptionally clever can add sides, front door and a little "roof" to keep the panel out of the weather.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question though. The question is how do you keep water from coming in the screw holes and what type of screws are appropriate?

Comment: @Nick  It's not really up to you.  The panel's labeling and instructions must be followed since the UL listing is contingent on doing so.  I don't deal much with temp panels but I see a lot of long term panels, and I have yet to find an outdoor meter or panel that *didn't* have a carpet of crud at the bottom from dust and water ingress.   The birdhouse is the best option I've ever seen.